# Call a WCF service from Silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, web-services, .net-4.0

I have a simple service with a single operational contract method called Sum

```
[OperationContact]
int sum(int i, int q);
```

When I am integrating the web service into a Silverlight app, adding this code into the main page:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
```

it doesn't call sum method. Moreover it shows:

```
obj.sumAsync(int i, int q)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight doesn't allow creation of a sync proxy of Web Services. It uses an async service proxy model. There will be two properties for each OperationContract in Silverlight:

```
obj.sumAsync(int i, int q, object state)
obj.sumAsyncCompleted; // Event
```

You should try this:

```
private void CallMethod()
{    
    obj.sumAsync(2,2);
    obj.sumAsyncCompleted += (s,e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                   MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: How to bind this e.result with datagrid in a silverlight?

Comment: if you are using MVVM pattern that is a preferred way of developing silverlight apps you should create a ViewModel and expose a public public property of the collection you want to bind to the grid. but if you want to use event based programming you can use "datagrid1.ItemsSource = e.Result;"

Answer (score 1):

Are you have marked the method with `[OperationContact]`. "operational contact" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight works with asynchronous programming model. Thus, the service calls are also asynchronous.
You have to register the callback of the service operation before calling the async wcf method:

```
obj.SumAsyncCompleted += SumAsyncCompleted;
obj.sumAsync(1, 2);

void SumAsyncCompleted(object sender, SumAsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //do something with e.Result
}
```